# how can I ensure that the email address I sent an invitation to is the one responding.?

Tags: javascript, http, security, https

So I am sending an invite to an email address for the person to click on a  to respond. They could click on the href or cut and paste it in the browser. I want to ensure that only the original person I sent the mail to is the one responding. So no forwarding of the invitation or sharing the link. I know I could put the target email address in the href as a return parameter but that could be manipulated. Is there a secure way to store the target email address in the link to be returned?
 EDIT:
So I know I can just send a confirm email after the person accept the invite and register. I can also save the original email address and force the invitee to use that to register then send a verification email but all this seems very round about is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the threat you are trying to protect from ?
Can you give more details about the signup process and the problem you are trying to solve ?
There isn't a sure way to know if whoever signing in is actually the user that received the e-mail but it shouldn't actually matter

Comment: @Yoni Jah When I send a invitation via email for you to click on to accept I don't want you to pass that link around for others to accept by pasting the link in the browser. SO I need to ensure the person I sent it to is the person responding

Comment: I understand that part. But why don't you want me to pass the e-mail around ? why do you care ? What are you afraid that will happen ?

Comment: @Yoni Jah.....LOL...It's like a private invitation only those who receive it should attend.....somewhat like a RSVP

Comment: Ok but what happens if user follow the link in the e-mail get the invitation and than transfer the actual invitation to a friend ?

Comment: @Yoni Jah......The link is the invitation!! Once you click the link you are verifying acceptance of the invitation. So its the link you would have to pass around. So if I pass my link to you  (via cut and paste) and you stick it in your browser you should be rejected since you weren't invited. Apparently the only way to do this for now is to save the original email and use email verification. So anyone can accept the invitation but they would be accepting on behalf of the original invitee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that the person responding to the invite doesn't claim you sent the invite to someone else by (when you send the invite email):

1. generating a unique token
2. storing that token in your database alongside the email address
3. using that token to identify the email address when the invitation is accepted

However, as you said, the email can be forwarded. If you send an invitation to Alice and she forwards it to Bob, then there is nothing stopping Bob accepting it on Alice's behalf.

You can warn Alice, in the email, that the link is private and should not be forwarded.

Since the invitation will be associated with Alice's email address, if she ignores that advice, then she will still be able to use any password reset features you implement to gain control from Bob.

You can also send Alice a "You accepted the invitation. If this was a mistake, click here to cancel." email.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

But how you choose to implement it is up to you. I would personally one-way hash the Email with etc sha256. You could lets say, base it on the database users following things.

- User id
- Email
- Send timestamp

So you would have a string like:

```
1234-user@domain.tld-1528789712
```

And so on, the combination of things to put together and then hash is up to you. Granted, don't just hash the email as-is - Then it's still easy to "manipulate". Don't forget to save the hash in your database to, so you can work with it later or at least make sure that the things your have in your string can be recalled later on.

So you would include something like this in both your tracking pixel and href link. (I assume you have a tracking pixel as well, so you can track when they open the email but perhaps don't click the link)

```
?source=ba1159374805fb1c3129afd4811c7be072bd9205d88237c8a957a1dfdf6dd00c
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input